# How to do this in codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, resize

Does anyone know how to make resize.php to work in codeigniter?

Below is my code used before CI and it worked perfectly fine before I decided to upgrade, now I'm facing this issue.

```
<img class="media-object" src="funcs/resize.php?src=customers/400.jpg&w=60" alt="...">
```

I have tried the code below, but with no luck!

```
<img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url();?>funcs/resize.php?src=<?php echo base_url('customers/400.jpg'); ?>&w=60" alt="...">
```

I also gave this a try:

```
<img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url();?>funcs/resize.php?src=<?php echo base_url();?>customers/400.jpg&w=60" alt="...">
```

I am new to CI and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Try after load `url` helper `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` or try `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`

Comment: i would set this as a library and call it when you feel like using it.

Comment: @CodeGodie I have been thinking about your suggestion, how to do that?

Comment: are you on now? maybe we can work on it remotely through Teamviewer

Comment: Hey.. cool. I'll be on in another hour. If u can wait for me then I can help.  See u later.

Comment: maybe i'll do some research for now because i am not able to pay you. no income for living yet! ^_^ thanks